# Razor page: why the first parameter is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

I have a simple Razor page with a list of transactions. I'm trying to implement paging for it. I've added the following method in page model:

```
public async Task OnGetAsync(int? page, int? rows)
{
    //The logic
}
```

When I call this method by the URL:

```
/transactions
```

It works as expected: page and rows are both equal to null.

However, if I try to call this method by the following URL:

```
/transactions?page=3&rows=2
```

The rows equal to 2, but the page is null. That looks weird for me.
Why does it work like that?
I know that I can create a property and use it from the request:

```
[BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
public int CurrentPage { get; set; }
```

But I wanted to know why the page parameter has a null value an use it if it is possible.

Comment: Is page a reserved word?

Comment: I'm using a 3d party grid for paging, and it uses this notation for paging: page and rows. So, we can say that 'page' is a reserved word.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/8010

Comment: I meant a reserved word in asp.net / Razor.

Comment: It is not reserved, but there is a Page property in a base class, PageModel.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I've got it now.

Comment: Here's a link to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#reserved-routing-names), too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word 'page' is reserved in asp.net/razor and can't be used directly as a method's parameter.

To fix my problem, I had to use:

```
public async Task OnGetAsync([FromQuery] int? page, int? rows)
```